# Access child methods in Python Django

Tags: python, django

I have a real life case that can be solved using polymorphism like in `Java` Where we can create a list of objects that belongs to the same type. However each object might have an override or extra fields.

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def speak(self):
        return "I am an animal"


class Cat(Animal):

    def speak(self):
        """ OVERRIDE """
        return "MEAOO"


class Dog(Animal):

    def speak(self):
        """ OVERRIDE """
        return "WOOOOF"
```

What I need now is to get all the animals but let each animal to use it's speak method. I was not able to to do that as below.

```
>>> c = Cat(name="MyCAT")
>>> c.save()
>>> d = Dog(name="MyDOG")
>>> d.save()
>>> animals = Animal.objects.all()
>>> animals
[<Animal: Animal object>, <Animal: Animal object>]
>>> for a in animals:
...     a.speak()
... 
'I am an animal'
'I am an animal'
>>>
```

To me the output should be like the below

```
'MEAOO'
'WOOOOF'
```

Is there anyway to do a similar thing in Django?

Comment: This is because you are pulling the Animals from the `Animal` object, which is defining the `speak()` method  as 'I am an animal'.  If you query from their appropriate models your data should be instantiated properly.

Comment: For details on model inheritance see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Comment: You need subclasses...try modelutils http://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem recently. I had a few subclasses, and all of them had slightly different "speak" methods.

What I basically do is create a `downcast` function in my parent class, which checks for related sub class instances. This works because when you subclass models, django links them via `OneToOneField`, which can be traversed both ways:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    _downcast = None
    # to store the subclass instance, so that
    # subsequent calls don't hit the database

    def speak(self):
        return "I am an animal"

    def downcast(self):
        if self._downcast is None:
            if hasattr(self, 'cat'):
                self._downcast = self.cat
            elif hasattr(self, 'dog'):
                self._downcast = self.dog

        return self._downcast


class Cat(Animal):
    def speak(self):
        """ OVERRIDE """
        return "MEAOO"


class Dog(Animal):
    def speak(self):
        """ OVERRIDE """
        return "WOOOOF"
```

Basically, you just kinda...go for it, and ask your database if this `Animal` does, in fact, have a related `Cat` row:

```
>>> a = Animal.objects.all().first() #let's assume this is a cat
>>> a.speak()
I am an animal
>>> a.downcast().speak()
MEAOO
```

Of course, this does query the database, so performance might take a hit. Consider your own scenario and run a few tests to see if this will work for you.